# Is it possible to turn a simple Subject into a BehaviorSubject?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a simple-but-hard RxJS related question. Suppose I want to subscribe to a Subject offered by a library I cannot modify, but I want that subscription to behave as though I would have subscribed to a BehaviorSubject. Is it than possible to do something like:

```
let plainSubject: Subject<string> = someLibrary.getSubject();
let behaviorSubject: BehaviorSubject<string> = BehaviorSubject.from(plainSubject);
let subscription = behaviorSubject.subscribe(() => foo());
```

I'm sorry if this question doesn't make any sense, my knowledge on RxJS is still rather basic. I'm not even sure if this is possible, since I haven't found any indication it is or isn't by Googling.

Thanks in advance!

Joshua

Answer (score 1):

you can:

```
let behaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject();
someLibrary.getSubject().subscribe(behaviorSubject);
behaviorSubject.subscribe(() => foo());
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the streams are immutable, you can "change" the subject to a behavior one.

But you totally can simulate one or create one from it :

```
const BS1$ = someLibrary.getSubject().pipe(
  startWith(undefined),
);

const BS2$ = new BehaviorSubject(undefined).pipe(
  switchMap(v => someLibrary.getSubject())
);
```

`startWith` makes the stream start with a given value, `switchMap` changes the value of the initial stream to the one provided.

THey both come from `'rxjs/operators'`.

Choose your weapon !

Comment: Seems like `BS2$` wont behave like `BehaviorSubject`, rather it will **immediately** switch subscriber to another stream, no? IMHO, the simplest way to turn `Subject` into `BehaviorSubject` is to subscribe latter to former: `subject.subscribe(behaviorSubject)`. Alternative, ways are: `publishBehavior()` with `connect()`. OR  `startWith` and `shareReplay(1)` (this option is not a 100% reproduction of BS behavior). Sorry if I'm missing something. GL

Comment: @kos don't be sorry, make an answer with that ! And for the second one, from what I see without having tested it is that each subscription will make an http call and return the response